# Need Help Diagnosing NSMergeConflict Error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, runtime-error, magicalrecord

I've been struggling to resolve an NSMergeConflict in an app I am working on. I know I could just change the merge policy, but I'm concerned about possibly corrupting the data since I don't know exactly which of the conflicting objects is correct and which is out of date. To make things even more complicated, the merge conflict is not actually in the object I am modifying and saving. Instead it appears to be coming from some related objects that I am not directly modifying.

The relationship graph looks something like this:

```
Order <<-----> Customer

Order <<-----> Rep

Rep   <<-----> Customer
```

where Order is the object I am modifying and saving and Customer and Rep are the objects that the merge error is complaining about.

What I really can't figure out is how to debug this issue and track down where my data is getting out of sync. Does anyone know of a good way to get more data about what is going on in my code? Is there a way to log what is in all the persistence contexts and see where they are diverging?

**Update:**
I changed the relationship between Order and Rep such that Rep no longer has a collection of Orders and that solved some of the issues. Unfortunately, that solution is not an option for the relationship between Order and Customer and I am still seeing errors there.

Here is a sample stacktrace of the error I am getting:

```
NSMergeConflict (0x1465972e0) for NSManagedObject (0x1462147a0) with objectID '0xd000000000a00008 <x-coredata://1F648314-CA44-4DA5-B437-07BFCB96D1E9/Customer/p40>' with oldVersion = 13 and newVersion = 14 and old object snapshot = {
address = "{\n    cmpnts =     (\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = \"2318 W 5TH AVE\";\n            \"short_name\" = \"2318 W 5TH AVE\";\n            types =             (\n                \"street_address\"\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = GARY;\n            \"short_name\" = GARY;\n            types =             (\n                locality\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = IN;\n            \"short_name\" = IN;\n            types =             (\n                \"administrative_area_level_1\"\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = \"Lake County\";\n            \"short_name\" = \"Lake County\";\n            types =             (\n                \"administrative_area_level_2\"\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = \"46404-1331\";\n            \"short_name\" = \"46404-1331\";\n            types =             (\n                \"postal_code\"\n            );\n        }\n    );\n    lat = \"41.60221\";\n    lng = \"-87.366285\";\n    loc = \"2318 W 5TH AVE, GARY, IN, 46404-1331\";\n}";
buyingGroup = "<null>";
compositeName = "20/20 EYE SPECIALIST (#385468)";
created = "2014-10-29 19:36:43 +0000";
"created_by_id" = 5451215fe4b007ffb46431bf;
"current_due" = 0;
customer = 385468;
customerTotal = "0xd0000000db74000a <x-coredata://1F648314-CA44-4DA5-B437-07BFCB96D1E9/CustomerTotals/p14045>";
detail = "0xd00000000504000c <x-coredata://1F648314-CA44-4DA5-B437-07BFCB96D1E9/CustomerDetail/p321>";
"device_address_section_key" = 2;
"device_address_sort_key" = "2318 W 5TH AVE";
"device_city_section_key" = G;
"device_city_sort_key" = GARY;
"device_corp_ytd_gross" = 0;
"device_created_section_key" = "01/01/1980";
"device_customer_section_key" = 3;
"device_deleted" = 0;
"device_exported" = "<null>";
"device_last_view" = "2016-04-12 17:04:51 +0000";
"device_latitude" = "41.60221";
"device_loaded" = "2016-04-12 15:25:07 +0000";
"device_longitude" = "-87.366285";
"device_name_section_key" = 2;
"device_note_date" = "<null>";
"device_note_text" = "<null>";
"device_phone_section_key" = 2;
"device_phone_sort_key" = 2198850116;
"device_rolling_12_credits" = 0;
"device_rolling_12_net" = 0;
"device_rolling_12_rd" = 0;
"device_rolling_12_rx" = 0;
"device_state_section_key" = I;
"device_state_sort_key" = IN;
"device_updated" = "<null>";
"device_ytd_credits" = 0;
"device_ytd_gross" = 0;
"device_ytd_net" = 0;
"device_ytd_rd" = 0;
"device_ytd_rx" = 0;
"device_zip_section_key" = 4;
"device_zip_sort_key" = "46404-1331";
"dw_fax" = "";
"dw_open_date" = "1980-01-01 05:00:00 +0000";
"is_inherited" = 0;
jobsonCensus = "0xd000000001a4000e <x-coredata://1F648314-CA44-4DA5-B437-07BFCB96D1E9/JobsonCensus/p105>";
"jobson_census_id" = 5494225284aec464730b3aa1;
"last_order_date" = "<null>";
"last_sync" = "2016-04-12 15:58:20 +0000";
name = "20/20 EYE SPECIALIST";
primaryContact = "<null>";
"remote_id" = 545141cbe4b024c7a6033055;
"updated_at" = "2015-09-15 11:48:11 +0000";
"updated_by_id" = "<null>";
} and new cached row = {
    address = "{\n    cmpnts =     (\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = \"2318 W 5TH AVE\";\n            \"short_name\" = \"2318 W 5TH AVE\";\n            types =             (\n                \"street_address\"\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = GARY;\n            \"short_name\" = GARY;\n            types =             (\n                locality\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = IN;\n            \"short_name\" = IN;\n            types =             (\n                \"administrative_area_level_1\"\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = \"Lake County\";\n            \"short_name\" = \"Lake County\";\n            types =             (\n                \"administrative_area_level_2\"\n            );\n        },\n                {\n            \"long_name\" = \"46404-1331\";\n            \"short_name\" = \"46404-1331\";\n            types =             (\n                \"postal_code\"\n            );\n        }\n    );\n    lat = \"41.60221\";\n    lng = \"-87.366285\";\n    loc = \"2318 W 5TH AVE, GARY, IN, 46404-1331\";\n}";
    buyingGroup = "<null>";
    compositeName = "20/20 EYE SPECIALIST (#385468)";
    created = "2014-10-29 19:36:43 +0000";
    "created_by_id" = 5451215fe4b007ffb46431bf;
    "current_due" = 0;
    customer = 385468;
    customerTotal = "0xd0000000db74000a <x-coredata://1F648314-CA44-4DA5-B437-07BFCB96D1E9/CustomerTotals/p14045>";
    detail = "0xd00000000504000c <x-coredata://1F648314-CA44-4DA5-B437-07BFCB96D1E9/CustomerDetail/p321>";
    "device_address_section_key" = 2;
    "device_address_sort_key" = "2318 W 5TH AVE";
    "device_city_section_key" = G;
    "device_city_sort_key" = GARY;
    "device_corp_ytd_gross" = 0;
    "device_created_section_key" = "01/01/1980";
    "device_customer_section_key" = 3;
    "device_deleted" = 0;
    "device_exported" = "<null>";
    "device_last_view" = "2016-04-12 17:04:51 +0000";
    "device_latitude" = "41.60221";
    "device_loaded" = "2016-04-12 15:25:07 +0000";
    "device_longitude" = "-87.366285";
    "device_name_section_key" = 2;
    "device_note_date" = "<null>";
    "device_note_text" = "<null>";
    "device_phone_section_key" = 2;
    "device_phone_sort_key" = 2198850116;
    "device_rolling_12_credits" = 0;
    "device_rolling_12_net" = 0;
    "device_rolling_12_rd" = 0;
    "device_rolling_12_rx" = 0;
    "device_state_section_key" = I;
    "device_state_sort_key" = IN;
    "device_updated" = "<null>";
    "device_ytd_credits" = 0;
    "device_ytd_gross" = 0;
    "device_ytd_net" = 0;
    "device_ytd_rd" = 0;
    "device_ytd_rx" = 0;
    "device_zip_section_key" = 4;
    "device_zip_sort_key" = "46404-1331";
    "dw_fax" = "";
    "dw_open_date" = "1980-01-01 05:00:00 +0000";
    "is_inherited" = 0;
    jobsonCensus = "0xd000000001a4000e <x-coredata://1F648314-CA44-4DA5-B437-07BFCB96D1E9/JobsonCensus/p105>";
    "jobson_census_id" = 5494225284aec464730b3aa1;
    "last_order_date" = "<null>";
    "last_sync" = "2016-04-12 16:06:52 +0000";
    name = "20/20 EYE SPECIALIST";
    primaryContact = "<null>";
    "remote_id" = 545141cbe4b024c7a6033055;
    "updated_at" = "2015-09-15 11:48:11 +0000";
    "updated_by_id" = "<null>";
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? If there is something wrong with the question, let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: Not sure why you where down voted, but you could add some things to help us help you. Can you show us the description of your merge conflict? How's your core data stack setup? How are you writting/editing your objects? The more context you can provide us the more we can help.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but you could try turning the customer and rep objects back into faults before saving.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to my that the relationship from `Customer` to `Rep` is redundant, unless it is completely unrelated to the `Order` entity. If Reps are linked to Customers only via the Orders, you could get the Reps for a customer like this:

```
Set(arrayLiteral: customer.orders.map { $0.rep })
```

As for logging more debug output you could switch on sql debugging, although you would have to extrapolate what Core Data is doing. (Add `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` to the Run Scheme.)

If updating orders affects your Users or Reps you could check if you have some delete rule with unintended consequences.

Comment: Unfortunately, the relationship between Rep and Customer is not redundant.

Comment: Then updating orders should not affect it, unless you have some cascade delete rule that deletes users or reps.